# How to deploy licensed fonts that can't go into version-control with Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, fonts, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I am using Capistrano to deploy my Rails application to a VPS (as shown in [episode 335 on railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps)). I have some custom fonts I'm using for the application and don't want to check them into source-control for licensing reasons (See clarification at bottom).

What's the best way to go about this? Should I edit the deploy.rb file to sftp the `assets/webfonts` directory from my local computer? Maybe I just need to copy them manually to the `my_app/shared/assets` directory on the VPS, but I'd rather it be automated as part of the deploy task.

Here's my current deploy.rb file:

```
require "rvm/capistrano"
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "ip_address", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "armory"
set :user, "username"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :github_user, "gorrillamcd"
set :repository, "git@github.com:#{github_user}/Armory.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.base.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/initializers/stripe.rb #{release_path}/config/initializers/stripe.rb"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

**Edit:** Sorry for being so vague beforehand. I'm using Museo Slab from myfonts.com and a public repo on github (check my user profile if you want to see it). I read through the license and found this:

> `3.` The Licensed Webfont(s) may be used on any Website owned or controlled by the Licensee
>
> `4.` Agencies responsible for multiple clients’ Websites, for example web design agencies or hosting providers, may not share a single Webfont license across multiple clients’ Websites.

Those two lines of the license make me believe that checking the font into a public repository would be against the license, since it could be used on sites that are not mine without obtaining a new license for the font (even though they were free to begin with). I imagine that other people have had this problem before. So my question is, **What's the normal/best way to handle deploy, with Capistrano, fonts (or any file for that matter) that can't be checked into source control?**

Comment: You're allowed to serve them to anyone who asks for them over the web, but not allowed to check them into source control? I'm finding it hard to make suggestions without more information about what you can and can't do.

Comment: I agree with willglynn .. licensing reasons should not really prevent you from checking them into source control .. webfonts are usually limited in their use on domains, but not in their binary distribution.. I'd suggest you just check them into your sourcecontrol..

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. I'm using Museo Slab from myfonts.com and I have a public repository. I was under the impression that that could fall under "distribution" since someone could fork the repository and have the font that way, but someone can correct me if I'm wrong. It'd definitely make it much easier to put them in the repo.

Comment: There is a difference between a local repository and Licences. If you include the licence in or with the font files, you should be able to put them in a public repository without any problem unless stated otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would pack the web fonts in an archive and put that archive somewhere separate from the repository. (Amazon S3 is a prime candidate.) Then, I'd have the release process retrieve and unpack this archive at deploy time.

This lets you put your entire app in your public repository -- the Capistrano scripts, the Rake tasks, etc. -- but leaves the actual font binaries out, with their location specified as a matter of configuration. This is consistent with [12-factor app principles](http://www.12factor.net/), treating these webfonts as an external resource needed by but not contained within your application.

You could, for example, specify a `WEBFONTS_URL` environment variable, and add a `fetch_webfonts` Rake task. This task would automatically pull these resources into your application, and would do nothing in the case that `WEBFONTS_URL` is unspecified -- e.g. if someone else did a checkout of your repo without having these fonts. (You could even make the task do appropriate things with stylesheets, ensuring that the fresh-checkout users get a working app without 404ing on font files.) Rake allows you to add dependencies to existing tasks, so you can ensure this happens automatically as part of `assets:precompile`, which Capistrano very likely already invokes.

Additionally, this approach works equally well on development and production: you can take a fresh checkout of your own repo, specify the appropriate `WEBFONTS_URL`, and end up with a working set of fonts on your local machine. (The [dotenv](http://opensoul.org/blog/archives/2012/07/24/dotenv/) gem makes it easy to get development configuration into environment variables, keeping all your environments consistent.) Just be sure that you `.gitignore` the results so you don't accidentally make them public after all.

Answer (score 1):

You could upload/synchronize the fonts directory using `rsync`. For example:

Add your IP/domain to a separate variable:

```
set :host, "ip_address"
server host, :web, :app, :db, primary: true
```

And add a task to run

```
`rsync -vz app/assets/webfonts #{user}@#{host}:#{shared_path}/assets/webfonts`
```

Then symlink it into the current version of your application like is done already in the deploy script with database.yml and stripe.rb

Comment: rsync feels hackish here, considering Capistrano already has an open SSH connection to the proper hosts with the proper credentials, knows all the paths, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I agree with @willglynn, I know capistrano can use scp or sftp for file transfer, however, if rsync has some benefit over those other methods, please let me know.